# How to scrape multiple classes using R?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to get the prices from [gittigidiyor.com](https://www.gittigidiyor.com/bilim-muhendislik) but the problem is some classes are different if there is any discount. Normally, p class is "fiyat price-txt robotobold price" but in other case it is "fiyat robotobold price-txt".

Here is my code shown below:

```
    read_html(url) %>% 
          html_nodes("div p") %>% 
          html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="fiyat price-txt robotobold price"]') %>%  
          #html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@class="fiyat robotobold price-txt"]') %>% 
          html_text()
```

How can i add other class into my code and get all of them together "respectively"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not just do `read_html(url) %>% html_nodes(".price-txt")` since the price-txt class is present in both

Comment: Think simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i add other class into my code and get all of them together
>   "respectively"

Use css Or syntax

```
html_nodes('.fiyat.price-txt.robotobold.price, .fiyat.robotobold.price-txt'
```

That will match on either though, as in comments, you can try selecting for a single shared class. This is more robust than using multi-values.

e.g.

```
html_nodes('.price-txt, .price-txt')   # possibly just .robotobold or even just .fiyat  depending on rest of html
```